# Rails: How can I relate to an object through an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm adding this reputation system [(twiiter rep system)](https://github.com/NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system/tree/rails4) to  [Act_As_Taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)
so, right now I want to add the reputation to the Taggings table, like the following:

```
#config/initializers/act_as_taggable_on.rb


ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.class_eval do
    has_reputation :post_points,
    :source => :user # this is where I'm stuck
end
```

I want to say user through the Tags user_id, how can I right that in ruby syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out this blog post on how to build a blog. Scroll down to section 13 which shows how to use tags and taggings models and how to associate them. It may help you out a bit.

http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html

```
      has_many :taggings
      has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```